# Kubernetes service gateway timeout

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kube-dns

I have two k8s services named as **A** and **B** in **same** namespace. **Service A** does curl to **Service B** and **Service B** talks outside of the cluster and surves to the request.
If I port-forward to **Service B** and then Curl from my machine to http://localhost/something which is Service B then it works fine.
But when I deploy **Service A** in the cluster which does the same curl but with url as http://B.namespace/something then I get

```
504 Gateway Timeout
upstream request timeout
```

P.S: Service B takes around 2 mins to get the info from outside of cluster

Any idea, how can I approach this?
TIA

Comment: can you show these services from the cluster? the `kubectl get svc` output.

Comment: Its literally A and B

Comment: From my machine curl takes around 2 mints but in k8s there might be some timeout. I get this timout after 30 secs

Comment: There are no service-to-service timeouts. And curl timeout is 5 or 10 mins. It's impossible to come up with anything with this information. who is throwing that error? may be your application is serving on localhost. you would need to change the serving app address to be `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: What do you mean `Service A does curl to Service B`? Pod which is endpoint of A svc can curl pod from B svc? Please provide your env details, svc and how you tested this connection.